# VueJS best way apply css from child to parrents

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

VueJS what is best way apply css from child to parrents?
I have many page with layout left\right\menu\tables\colunm\etc. All routes render in deep path. Today there are page(component) what need apply css style to parrent on N level up. how i can do it ?

Comment: if you have many components with many N levels then go with Vuex

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple EventBus at global level:

```
const eventBus = new Vue();
```

And then `eventBus.$emit('signal-name', ...args)`

Then you can do an array of things like

`eventBus.$on(name, callback)` -> Create a listener to receive emits

`eventBus.$once(name, callback)` -> Receive once and remove listener

`eventBus.$off(name, callback)` -> Remove listener

You can pass some boolean or CSS classes:

`eventBus.$emit('signal-name', true)` -> and then show something based on it 
`eventBus.$emit('signal-name', ['is-white', 'is-bold'])`

Note: for `$off`:

```
  * If no arguments are provided, remove all event listeners;
  * If only the event is provided, remove all listeners for that event;
  * If both event and callback are given, remove the listener for that specific callback only.
```

Comment: While this can work, its better to go with a state machine like Vuex, or even a simple object. Events are easily missed depending on when the listeners/components are created/fired etc. A state object would always reflect the right value regardless if the 'listener' was active when it changed.

Comment: I generally go for state management tools when I do things related to data. But for actions within distant corners of the app, I prefer EventBus :-)